# How to Ingest data into AWS Kinesis from Particle cloud JSON web hook

Tags: json, webhooks, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-api-gateway

Does anyone have experience or any idea to send a JSON payload to ingest data into AWS Kinesis?
I use Ubidots right now to visualize data but now I want to use AWS QuickSights for analyzing and visualizing it. 
This is how a web hook looks :

```
{
  "Alerts": "{{Alerts}}",
  "Resets": "{{Resets}}",
  "Battery": "{{Battery}}",
  "Distance": "{{Distance}}",
  "Temperature": "{{Temperature}}"
}
```

I want an API endpoint through which I can send the data to the cloud.

Is it necessary to send the data to AWS IoT Core and then send it to kinesis from there or I can directly send it from Webhook to Kinesis. Once I have data in the Kinesis, I can load it into the QuickSights dashboard.
Thanks,
Hannan

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example leveraging API Gateway. The API Gateway endpoint triggers a [Lambda function](https://gist.github.com/mlapida/60748a378d4986170b6f) that sends the payload to DynamoDB, but this could easily be a Kinesis Stream. If you would like to bypass the Lambda function, [you can also configure API Gateway as a proxy for Kinesis directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html).

```
{
  "event": "sendSleep",
  "url": "https://[yourendpoint].execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/ParticleSleepV1",
  "requestType": "Post",
  "headers": {
        "x-api-key" : "[yourapikey]"
   },
   "json": {
        "name": "{{SPARK_EVENT_NAME}}",
        "data": "{{SPARK_EVENT_VALUE}}",
        "source": "{{SPARK_CORE_ID}}",
        "published_at": "{{SPARK_PUBLISHED_AT}}"
    },
  "mydevices": true,
  "noDefaults": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I created an API Endpoint using AWS API Gateway and setup a stream which sends data to Firehose and then to S3 from there. I have the API Endpoint, But since I followed a guide on medium, I am not sure about the JSON template they have used.

Comment: Since you have used Particle's Webhooks, Can you suggest me how I should make my Webhooks so that it sends device ID and timestamp with every push. This is the tutorial that I followed, Also Can you tell me some reference where I can see on adding a new record on every line. Sorry if its all obvious, I'm new to it. This is the link [https://medium.com/a-tale-of-2-from-data-to-information/how-to-build-an-event-pipeline-within-1-hour-and-minimum-lines-of-code-in-aws-eb1bd0bb6cd2]